# In Android 4.4+ versions, geofence not working over 3G/WiFi

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-geofence

I am using the sample application(Creating and Monitoring Geofences) provided by Android.

On Android 4.4+ (KitKat )versions only, I am not able to add/delete Geofences over 3G or WiFi. Every time I am getting error code 1000(" Add Geofences: Failure, error code 1000").

Just by enabling GPS(it doesn't matter whether GPS is fixed or not), everything works fine but accompanied with the problem of battery drain.

Is there any alternative solution? If yes, then please guide me.

Any help or guidance will be well appreciated.

**Note**: I have tested on Nexus 5(4.4.4), Nexus 4(4.4) and Samsung Galaxy S4(4.4.2).
On Android 4.3 and below, everything works fine.

Comment: are you sure that you are connected to location client?

Comment: Hi Pankaj, thanks for reply. I am pretty sure that I am connected to Location Client. Because I getting the onConnected() callback of Location Client.

Comment: I have tested on my MotoG android 4.4.4.and it works perfectly fine

Comment: Hi Pankaj, is GPS disabled in your case?

Comment: no, I have enabled LocationServices. google-playservice Library primarily works on Location Services and geofence is depend on locationservices.you can't just add geofence after turning off gps